Chartjs: chart is blurry when using webworker
I am trying to use chart.js with webworker.
I am able to create the webworker and show the chart on the screen with the right dimensions.
The problem is: the chart is blurry and a bit "zoomed in". It's like the responsivness or the ratio is not working.
Hier is the differences:


These are the configuration i use for the chart :
const config: ChartOptions = {
    //...plugins etc...to avoid printing several lines
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  };
  const parentNode = document.getElementById("chart-parent") as HTMLDivElement;
  const canvas = document.getElementById("chart") as HTMLCanvasElement;

  const offscreenCanvas = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
  worker.postMessage(
    {
      canvas: offscreenCanvas,
      config,
      data: getChart(),
      sizes: { width: parentNode.clientWidth, height: parentNode.clientHeight },
    },
    [offscreenCanvas]
  );

// RESIZING  => not really working
function resize() {
  console.log("Rezise");
  worker.postMessage({
    sizes: { width: parentNode.clientWidth, height: parentNode.clientHeight },
  });
}

window.onresize = resize;

Html:
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

Css:
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 80vw;

  canvas#chart {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

In the worker, i instantiate the Chart with the given configuration and a simple array for the data.
let chart: Chart | null;
let myConfig: ChartConfiguration;
onmessage = function (event) {
  const { canvas, config, data, sizes } = event.data;
  myConfig = config;
  if (canvas && config && data) {
    chart = new Chart(canvas, {
      type: "line",
      options: config,
      data: {
        labels: data.map((row: { year: any }) => row.year),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Acquisitions by year",
            data: data.map((row: { count: any }) => row.count),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
  if (sizes && chart) {
    canvas.height = sizes.height;
    canvas.width = sizes.width;
    chart.resize();
  }
};

UPDATE: changing the devicePixelRatio to my window.devicePixelRatio in the option configuration looks to solve a part of my problem:  initial width/height/ratio and blurryness is OK but the responsiveness is not working...
  const config: ChartOptions = {
    //...plugins...
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    devicePixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
  };



Chart.js doesn't (yet?) support full features on an OfflineCanvas, see this line in the source code in connection to this file.

Even if support were enabled, the responsive mode is useless - the parent element is used to set the size of the canvas; but the offline canvas doesn't keep the connection to the original canvas parent element. devicePixelRatio is a good find, but if you resize the window, all you get is an image resize of the canvas, not a responsive redraw, see fiddle. As for interactivity, you'd have to translate events to the offline canvas, see this post.
